# Amazon RDS + PostgreSQL + accent + like

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, accent-insensitive, unaccent

I'm having a lot of troubles using the configuration described in the title.

My problem :

- I have a PostgreSQL DB 10.0 in AWS RDS
- The DB is configured with UTF-8
- I have a table with descriptions of diseases in french (so, with accents)
- I want to look for all the codes where the description has a specific word inside

For example, my search is :
`SELECT * FROM cim10 WHERE description LIKE '%anémie%' ORDER BY weight DESC` which works fine.

The problem is when I want to have the same results looking for '%anemie%' (without the accent).

I found that AWS RDS has the module unaccent installed which could solve my problems but when I try it I have an error in my lambda function :

[image]

Someone can help me find out the solution ? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

So, after posting the question I found the answer https://amzn.to/2yg6PWm :

You have to activate the extension by doing `CREATE EXTENSION [extension name]`

Then you can use it like this : `SELECT * FROM cim10 WHERE unaccent(description) LIKE unaccent('%' || [string you are looking for] || '%')`